# Automatically round floating point number with variable number of zeros after decimal point to first non zero digit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dealing with floating point numbers and need to display them on an widget on webpage which has limited width. I mostly use tofixed(2) for all my floating point number. But there are certain cases where there are numbers like: `0.0000000365468`, only `0.00` are printed because of tofixed(2). I cannot permanently set it to tofixed(8) as normal cases will take too much space then.

Is there any inbuilt functionality in javascript/jquery where I can automatically get round the number to the nearest meaningful number (in above case: `0.00000003` or `0.00000004` to be precise)?

Comment: `Math.log10()` would be a good place to start.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: `in above case: 0.00000003` but wouldn't that be wrong as the next number is `6` (I'm assuming the space is a typo)? Would you not want to return `0.00000004` in that case?

Comment: yes, space is a typo... I am ok with truncation/rounding anything. It would be great if I get 0.00000004 though @DarrenSweeney

Comment: Well `Math.log10(n)` returning a negative number would tell you that you've got something like 0.00000n.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's nothing built into JavaScript nor jQuery to do this. You'll need to find code for this or write your own.

Comment: unfortunately n will keep on varying @Pointy I cannot check for every logarithm till 10 (potentially). I am dealing with too many numbers.

Comment: Understand that the term "significant digits" isn't really correct here; that term means something else. It's not clear what your criteria are for showing the numbers in the first place. A string-based solution might be the right answer for all I know.

Comment: sorry for that @Pointy. Can you please edit the question which sounds mathematically correct

Comment: Edited the question... Thanks for suggestion @Pointy

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't want to show something like `37e-9` for that instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take the log<sub>10</sub> and use a threshold for taking the value.

```js
function f(x) {
    return x.toFixed(Math.log10(x) < -2 ? 8 : 2);
}

console.log(f(0.0000000365468));
console.log(f(0.000000365468));
console.log(f(0.00000365468));
console.log(f(0.0000365468));
console.log(f(0.000365468));
console.log(f(0.00365468));
console.log(f(0.0365468));
console.log(f(12.34));
```

A dynamic approach

```js
function f(x) {
    return x.toFixed(Math.max(-Math.log10(x) + 1, 2));
}

console.log(f(0.0000000365468));
console.log(f(0.000000365468));
console.log(f(0.00000365468));
console.log(f(0.0000365468));
console.log(f(0.000365468));
console.log(f(0.00365468));
console.log(f(0.0365468));
console.log(f(12.34));
```

Comment: I reckon that you meant *"base 10 log"* instead of *"logarithm of 10"*.

Comment: You're still counting there though - I'm assuming the OP would want  `console.log(f(0.0000000000000365468));` to return `0.00000000000004`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney it would be easy to adapt the answer for a dynamic result, if op says so.

Comment: for the sixth example, I would like the result as: 0.004

Comment: Nice solution, I would modify slightly `function f(x) {
    return x.toFixed(Math.log10(x) < -2 ? - 1* Math.log10(x)+1 : 2);
}` Just to remove the threshold part.

Comment: great! @AnkitJaiswal can you submit this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @KashyapKotak, Nina has updated the answer with this change. You can accept this, as there is no point duplicating the same answer.

Comment: great! Thanks Nina & Ankit

Answer (score 3):

I normally favour more readable code over performant code so here is my 2 cents.

I'm using recursion to trim the number to 2 decimal places if it's not zero I return if not I increase the number of decimal places it also rounds up the number for us :)

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

```js
const arr = [0.34, 0.567, 0.000045, 0.0000066, 0.000044]

console.log(arr.map(trimNumber))

function trimNumber(number, points = 2) {
  const trimmed = number.toFixed(points);

  if (trimmed != 0) return trimmed;

  return trimNumber(number, points + 1);
}
```

Comment: If you want to save a function call, `Number(0).toFixed(points)` is the same as `(0).toFixed(points)`

Comment: nice! good call

Comment: You solution is good, but I will be looking for performance as a priority. Thanks for your approach though :)

Comment: that's cool :) in most cases we don't need to micro-optimise but always good to know when to use the performant solution

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just use the Number prototype method [toPrecision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Number/toPrecision). It returns a String as well which suits your purposes quite nicely.

E.g.

```
const myNum = 0.000355;
const oneSigFig = myNum.toPrecision(1);
console.log(oneSigFig) // output: 0.0004
```

Comment: from MDN: "note that exponential notation might be returned in some circumstances: `console.log((1234.5).toPrecision(2)); // logs '1.2e+3'`"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toFixed` for bigger numbers and `toPrecision` or `toExponential` for smaller ones. You mention amount of space being an issue too, so the exponential notation that will be used for the smallest numbers seems to be a good idea.

```js
function toFixedOrPrecision(num) {
  if (num > 0.01) return num.toFixed(2);
  return num.toPrecision(1);
}

function toFixedOrExponential(num) {
  if (num > 0.01) return num.toFixed(2);
  return num.toExponential(0);
}

for (let n=123456789; n>1e-10; n/=10) console.log(toFixedOrPrecision(n));
for (let n=123456789; n>1e-10; n/=10) console.log(toFixedOrExponential(n));
```